# Joomla media manager открывается в новом окне

Tags: joomla, события

Добрый день! Пишу модуль для *Joomla 3.43*. В модуле есть кнопка "*Добавить отзыв*", при нажатии, в блок добавляются элементы, среди которых кнопка "*Добавить изображение*". После добавления элементов в блок, при клике на конпку "*Добавить изображение*", Media manager должен открываться в модальном окне, вместо этого происходит переход по ссылке. Но если я нажму на кнопку сохранить и после этого кликну "*Добавить изображение*" то менеджер откроется в модальном окне. Хотя после сохранения данных модуля элементы добавляются точно также. Вот код:

```js
function addComment(el){
    $html = '';
    var n = 'list'+i;
    document.id('selectlist').innerHTML += '<a class="modal btn" rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}" href="index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&fieldid='+n+'&folder=" title="Выбрать"> Выбрать</a>'
}
```

И кнопка, после нажатия на которую вызывается функция

```html
<ul class="select" id="selectlist">             
</ul>
<div>
    <a href="" class="add" onclick="addComment();return false;">Add Comment</a>
</div>
```

Подскажите что не так. Не знаю куда копать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: все библиотеки подключены?
ошибок в консоли нет?

Comment: Ошибок нет, все подключено...Но если модуль сохранить, то фунция addComment запускается при загрузке модуля с сохраненными данными. и в данном случае открывается модальное окно.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание! Причина в том что после сохранения модуля и загрузки всех данных по новой происходит инициализация модального окна SqueezeBox.initialize({}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может просто ваши кнопки не прибиндены автоматом к событию нажатия и появления модального окна? скорее всего после перезагрузки, JS библиотека просто начинает видеть ваши кнопки и все работает. То есть в момент создания, надо не просто создать кнопки, но и сделать рефреш вашей библиотеке или явно повесить события на нее.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сначала тоже об этом думал но приичина в SqueezeBox.initialize({})

Comment: получается мой ответ верный, но без кода ибо у вас его было мало в топике, если так, то отметьте мой ответ.